# SSIS package execution fails in Agent Job, does not fail anywhere else, no error message

Tags: security, ssis

Dev is in Visual Studio 2015, package deployed and runs (try to run but doesn’t)  on SQL Server 2014 SP3, uses package deployment model, store is on same server as DB.

Package is a test package, has a single node (OLE DB Source) that executes a simple query.
Logging is turned on, nothing written to logfile.  No error messages when viewing history of Agent Job.

SQL Server Agent service using:  NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT.

In VS, Package creator is my network account.
In any other location where credentials are used, I have used the same generic network acct we use for jobs and tasks.

Have tried package Security ProtectionLevel:  EncryptSensitiveWithPassword, EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey, Don’tSaveSensitive. No improvement.

I run the Agent Job manually (Start Job At Step…), I get a green check and success for “Start  Job” ,   the “execute” action has “in progress” and never completes or fails.  I must use the “Stop Job” to stop execution. No fail message anywhere.

As there is no error messages anywhere at all, I am thinking that the package wont even start any initial execution.
Package runs in Visual Studio, runs when executed in MSDB Store.  No where else.

I strongly suspect that I have missed something obvious in the config or deploy, just cant see it.

Comment: `store is on same server as DB` What does that mean? With package deployment model, you have database, file system or the package store which is just a special place on the file system? Could you script out the relevant step of your SQL Agent job? If you don't have `/rep eiw` ensure that is in there as it will surface errors, information and warning events which is usually where you find out what went awry.

Comment: I added EIW to the command line, it didn’t help.

‘Store is on same server as DB’:  Yes I had 3 options, and I choose ‘package store’ which is the same machine (server) as the DB, maybe that isnt important.  Also, I looked in the ‘…\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS’ folder and it is empty. Shouldn’t there be at least a file for the test project?  Should I alter permissions to ensure deployment  can write to that directory?

Answer (score 1):

I stopped the service that runs agent jobs: "SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER)". Restarted it with a different logon, a logon that is used to build and deploy the ssis project. Restarted the service. The original service was run under the "NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT" account , which seems to be a default account.  I guess that service needs to be 'compatible' with the SSIS project.